# Pandas read_csv reads rows wrongfully as dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a problem when trying to read a regular csv file with pandas.
The columns are just numbers from 0-159, the values are float and floating-point numbers.
examples for the values are 1.245406167676584e-13 , -14.781030514709872 , 0.28061249825016815.
And I would expect each column to have its corresponding number in a row.

[image: original csv]
However, when I read in the csv as per example in the picture above (the csv is at the end, sorry, I could not get a smaller one to reproduce this), I get the following data structure:
[image: wrong data structure from csv]

In this structure, each row is a dictionary of its own. The first 4 numbers are the key, the 5th is always the value of the column (although the wrong one). (value of first cell is -74.260196 for example)

How can I keep this from happening? I just want to read the csv as normal.

Csv data:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159
-28.72466306892318e12,16.966026399304525,-42.87239163479887,37.06969272107673,-74.2601964196411,57.915233690916786,-89.63410196434016,64.41009089917166,-98.67490642089729,67.1343290789727,-95.55111417210443,58.013282233594246,-76.32484819818251,42.11132556642663,-48.524290504722494,21.526589964168203,-13.8581233306059,-3.3490646092526433,22.84198653097978,-27.060896358727,54.382255845878014,-45.673473909527225,77.50880722737743,-57.791741228592976,89.56781809792449,-60.99336804220146,88.16348841894312,-56.11574199299081,76.86514428022184,-46.16717828337371,59.47716972301922,-32.752475257286164,39.820088490713246,-20.495941260416675,22.99935074984098,-10.523079594855439,10.88663389926389,-4.196380698527703,4.000935028546149,-0.9772293254528972,0.8609574288131829,-46.57054283319171,19.173016773335288,-122.4805546477765,41.742910475315824,-208.91998901446402,68.9664104196525,-257.479377604769,74.1446030525972,-282.24875512874866,77.90373111349169,-271.9070079387826,67.31928472555192,-217.9639123101401,48.55696873721421,-138.56835354764408,25.361218668551334,-39.98915690908285,-3.6731602010503646,64.7235138574192,-31.259854021448785,154.94427632476325,-52.533782321163265,221.0576060603368,-66.88535164334371,254.96243683781972,-70.60071237115383,251.5503449550602,-64.87873370201224,219.6325271034961,-53.756735801722286,169.89294378572342,-38.174554507004174,114.44452853083385,-24.221894115553884,66.24186369357932,-12.489356301147113,31.509425779676448,-5.011549296016099,11.523955561693546,-1.2324596975505553,2.3942274604386133,13.698544314233853,12.73370853971873,-52.86500337481437,29.570941419742685,-87.62956576633692,46.13278092029744,-111.67436913458086,50.51561043181823,-121.00678656606034,52.73871768373986,-116.34162689010873,45.990152440201086,-93.77626222289165,33.031020425879824,-59.46247366546009,17.13930792580037,-17.339720046909793,-2.5240093448743592,27.358558591981225,-21.200012975473076,66.19941324276897,-35.7192163946112,94.65397551469647,-45.43806304646717,108.9992926772042,-47.97784408098858,107.74571885528185,-44.16805179745866,94.46496252194154,-36.43785989536876,72.9893490627619,-25.982707486226108,49.579463942266266,-16.362206532868928,28.80367841198022,-8.45589399968555,13.867311815346214,-3.4405875266757437,5.10296002559008,-0.8957867120997663,1.082578692873228,-23.999999999999943,6.67032204596957e-14,1.245406167676584e-13,1.4703831719607764e-13,2.5632650422903316e-13,2.1125691421248602e-13,3.014305387567766e-13,2.5312420566727674e-13,3.263294721136611e-13,2.705119068247448e-13,3.0616848128832963e-13,2.6452732877735657e-13,2.513171654396122e-13,2.384625893321381e-13,1.7188502873295985e-13,1.992919679733673e-13,7.237692304769979e-14,1.566343367477935e-13,-3.181994344332885e-14,1.1841869015096767e-13,-1.2068261501707508e-13,8.829555432128558e-14,-1.8058564072506982e-13,6.682713886443883e-14,-2.0745844624845483e-13,5.6610293783247607e-14,-2.0269973181573283e-13,6.458216506803031e-14,-1.711473367247439e-13,9.522438100091545e-14,-1.1813075741260172e-13,1.407680983530586e-13,-6.384802726290595e-14,1.762883615109664e-13,-2.1819592555661978e-14,1.8925477518271193e-13,5.925989391252889e-15,2.007038813065584e-13,2.897604295251666e-14,2.2096332135585036e-13,3.863827871501308e-14
-21.413867228646293,-2.5282711935618956,-6.93084627003621,-5.011281934809228,-11.18544892521373,-13.82494999878299,-14.372899121058246,-11.704558468672218,-14.970243065475522,-14.073951582795912,-15.441519819745524,-11.04957060042677,-11.611656380494479,-8.886315160681761,-8.104091917250543,-4.1300354629158385,-1.8360509557227367,0.3317104638105255,3.239224351426863,5.111004105366378,8.72047049244835,8.93742416563495,11.876672813644635,11.264631735274337,14.111682201447774,12.148667163684236,13.691806605063794,10.933643879890152,12.163598127441935,9.601211444327774,9.335226248842032,6.633907879820257,6.456949359407382,4.532033345632565,3.7030605445882094,2.366556112221847,1.7629581082433585,1.052957855574088,0.6730330611544868,0.29518625569391177,0.13194177349972525,-22.528399330936658,-10.218402616297713,-4.841101019146182,-21.25295346847763,-7.706372249262545,-42.27447847181991,-9.758007395302544,-41.61013373069367,-9.993084664686297,-46.74327139232265,-10.974479508239385,-38.199306394971465,-7.80494467584213,-29.854035615932748,-5.78695614348123,-14.004964936216076,-1.1890878347360148,1.503988496991579,2.096362889577231,17.63817487718735,6.05890636045365,30.621073579140752,7.912624038640294,38.396988470145736,9.816518143261789,41.16096191617698,9.245731854057963,37.56080833989963,8.43976069439306,32.01753319226937,6.512702083133027,22.555957617105854,4.498060929047554,14.767180923240758,2.636319396719282,7.776400456117172,1.294125481417865,3.3313747492173245,0.49160806311104105,0.877104013716125,0.1297128903509163,33.784476973265065,-7.484384792088839,46.470200065782855,-14.530635628256524,75.92586657472982,-23.336327003383527,100.23164849210958,-25.809578434144882,107.44090289970589,-27.413430060957342,102.19849070583751,-23.343303094753438,83.65110890217584,-17.557349687746335,52.725271313432636,-8.486447137904806,16.060518010495674,1.1757650556959078,-23.350614386598963,10.879400186469855,-57.55346243162423,18.50569211371895,-83.25475720762397,23.196146642573286,-95.42059935070722,24.717891750692065,-95.18353525298454,22.723895459431446,-83.854396011233,18.8174210538905,-65.25258471631356,13.435649100641283,-45.054078634228105,8.466954555817326,-26.69324356618218,4.40121621281668,-13.216509648249286,1.7749897729440731,-5.041643821943503,0.466433937508152,-1.2130589071662057,-23.999999999999943,6.67032204596957e-14,1.245406167676584e-13,1.4703831719607764e-13,2.5632650422903316e-13,2.1125691421248602e-13,3.014305387567766e-13,2.5312420566727674e-13,3.263294721136611e-13,2.705119068247448e-13,3.0616848128832963e-13,2.6452732877735657e-13,2.513171654396122e-13,2.384625893321381e-13,1.7188502873295985e-13,1.992919679733673e-13,7.237692304769979e-14,1.566343367477935e-13,-3.181994344332885e-14,1.1841869015096767e-13,-1.2068261501707508e-13,8.829555432128558e-14,-1.8058564072506982e-13,6.682713886443883e-14,-2.0745844624845483e-13,5.6610293783247607e-14,-2.0269973181573283e-13,6.458216506803031e-14,-1.711473367247439e-13,9.522438100091545e-14,-1.1813075741260172e-13,1.407680983530586e-13,-6.384802726290595e-14,1.762883615109664e-13,-2.1819592555661978e-14,1.8925477518271193e-13,5.925989391252889e-15,2.007038813065584e-13,2.897604295251666e-14,2.2096332135585036e-13,3.863827871501308e-14
-12.125493312295697,-34.09794657251972,38.069088966261916,-76.20309075312167,65.78897044854793,-102.0312361515325,80.60529297455379,-123.58636739296253,88.64140073901794,-126.40928586763523,84.81641277200197,-109.63248775411394,68.54114006197086,-80.27814316518379,43.318317313309386,-39.87167341087051,12.611565462783032,7.0155868493336575,-19.883558562374986,51.973657170324984,-48.28683472152177,87.54987882013181,-69.01998092472982,109.2599415624865,-79.60448405719227,115.83298874020483,-78.71836229433853,106.57679185027004,-68.79050121330484,86.29487343013159,-53.38432345324279,61.64555309782151,-36.03045840834482,37.49303117734715,-21.01718682371514,18.955157795848468,-10.129766845241473,7.25348156793155,-3.8057557863291893,1.509289022457166,-0.8454823358547632,9.382804542167415,-54.310278558612865,149.97685399303987,-121.54251408987733,254.68351992876472,-161.3999693575505,318.45177720345674,-196.1709050320829,347.7705265120273,-200.41097100870275,332.8017843795614,-174.06031666628934,269.1226025368736,-127.81311629765261,170.66817958195784,-63.0631956261192,49.95107674053664,10.853706988213343,-77.40961558167837,82.08773755730195,-188.9848776941043,138.74523792339494,-270.4251044748159,173.01988153330134,-311.7271073546612,183.62243791083392,-308.78676820608877,169.13719986322485,-270.4184162059884,137.0398336527759,-210.07068616916618,98.18901242285897,-142.63369353435172,59.74236147974591,-83.56976149062885,30.456934784249782,-40.49013423793536,11.720249947109785,-15.173528851765308,2.6066725925994914,-3.4694316211792855,39.946378152881685,-14.068748243927935,79.15761667238796,-30.16212888970618,134.43889210146241,-42.27956245431031,168.0057401214446,-49.70549302444846,183.39491677651472,-51.427639882629734,175.32283204020933,-44.20346376023586,141.63704567916832,-32.58383518672739,90.05011333691964,-16.10283543999799,26.404326126748916,2.7105516186781684,-40.638114958099465,20.910683947576747,-99.5253277233919,35.391033292956514,-142.43075302545498,44.13943552320413,-164.19007623283915,46.94194756745503,-162.64579512894062,43.04770692440849,-142.51868794018966,35.06481791322439,-110.81735779544111,24.95466533237414,-75.29241041455396,15.311034651748727,-44.20619053147193,7.76488334934033,-21.461113179911518,3.026243575741641,-8.01698884896578,0.6707031900634406,-1.8150452311083567,-23.999999999999943,6.67032204596957e-14,1.245406167676584e-13,1.4703831719607764e-13,2.5632650422903316e-13,2.1125691421248602e-13,3.014305387567766e-13,2.5312420566727674e-13,3.263294721136611e-13,2.705119068247448e-13,3.0616848128832963e-13,2.6452732877735657e-13,2.513171654396122e-13,2.384625893321381e-13,1.7188502873295985e-13,1.992919679733673e-13,7.237692304769979e-14,1.566343367477935e-13,-3.181994344332885e-14,1.1841869015096767e-13,-1.2068261501707508e-13,8.829555432128558e-14,-1.8058564072506982e-13,6.682713886443883e-14,-2.0745844624845483e-13,5.6610293783247607e-14,-2.0269973181573283e-13,6.458216506803031e-14,-1.711473367247439e-13,9.522438100091545e-14,-1.1813075741260172e-13,1.407680983530586e-13,-6.384802726290595e-14,1.762883615109664e-13,-2.1819592555661978e-14,1.8925477518271193e-13,5.925989391252889e-15,2.007038813065584e-13,2.897604295251666e-14,2.2096332135585036e-13,3.863827871501308e-14
-12.443814181545712,-0.779742972501207,35.46271925365665,-1.0713430959730332,55.59917209577768,-4.444180728061166,76.53237133069723,-2.699100450821645,80.65274565576696,-3.48717315322838,78.67439029670224,-2.7334248863918305,62.57027352823641,-2.012683421001301,40.50564575992955,-1.2035773454143732,11.156204639891412,0.1297963377275013,-18.252306120977018,1.0864210029004528,-44.95716203610979,2.1422192874341026,-63.66738815172255,2.784672171356919,-73.40861444337301,2.9880299805264823,-72.32248999279741,2.6160937678994527,-63.778498272512984,2.4457388281902004,-48.75587932293529,1.6428876390519527,-33.384312625308034,1.2371619166217547,-19.19628833109976,0.6524063873151025,-9.176539186198763,0.3119835777933488,-3.256911223384156,0.09381516097267666,-0.6533186760152704,6.175374320669617,-1.659920482536208,132.94673619292143,-1.9511830486682329,215.75094403240672,-8.041250759613808,285.477407375372,-4.860132827761133,305.6340017284426,-5.677340146877335,294.1483114744587,-5.5808220715389165,236.7718618626109,-3.41269236482024,151.43568310980984,-2.486701247900934,43.69546338571588,0.13246340970364748,-67.98123130113659,1.7210823564717816,-167.18909719052022,3.400681798010776,-238.7727488210806,4.954850991377992,-274.86282648896105,4.9606947640803245,-272.10907318018104,4.7843092617082075,-239.4416393098253,4.504017767971821,-184.86197052726416,3.3314471952707554,-126.48988415766692,2.6150911146171896,-73.81787853280058,1.4782070275930301,-35.80516462435737,0.7925874778703128,-13.122624918944148,0.29460979190553943,-2.8816444331209183,36.287274217602864,7.533884887056847,61.37696102981825,16.393879773079995,99.6941384443596,24.766924121123175,130.33540857258927,28.911567002412838,140.26158950040542,29.529211488045167,134.60583190274465,25.642931314092646,108.7430668567604,19.180126647727302,69.26708954057187,9.18162907187632,20.062629685678,-1.1881098477427734,-31.18690344279684,-11.672572408405792,-76.553804824702,-20.205484860697826,-109.44074080626666,-25.217831200652334,-125.9128471533268,-26.873839993904124,-124.82921995434799,-24.92650923766527,-109.59478404167643,-20.47867178278849,-84.75999861806214,-14.781030514709872,-57.928619836170874,-9.247405177923108,-33.80675081878248,-4.940421623159597,-16.384713870015812,-2.017148181816816,-6.065107305744551,-0.5911294706244511,-1.3704990818520457,-23.999999999999943,6.67032204596957e-14,1.245406167676584e-13,1.4703831719607764e-13,2.5632650422903316e-13,2.1125691421248602e-13,3.014305387567766e-13,2.5312420566727674e-13,3.263294721136611e-13,2.705119068247448e-13,3.0616848128832963e-13,2.6452732877735657e-13,2.513171654396122e-13,2.384625893321381e-13,1.7188502873295985e-13,1.992919679733673e-13,7.237692304769979e-14,1.566343367477935e-13,-3.181994344332885e-14,1.1841869015096767e-13,-1.2068261501707508e-13,8.829555432128558e-14,-1.8058564072506982e-13,6.682713886443883e-14,-2.0745844624845483e-13,5.6610293783247607e-14,-2.0269973181573283e-13,6.458216506803031e-14,-1.711473367247439e-13,9.522438100091545e-14,-1.1813075741260172e-13,1.407680983530586e-13,-6.384802726290595e-14,1.762883615109664e-13,-2.1819592555661978e-14,1.8925477518271193e-13,5.925989391252889e-15,2.007038813065584e-13,2.897604295251666e-14,2.2096332135585036e-13,3.863827871501308e-14
-39.754794743744924,15.78882434231351,-94.72703002814102,34.90634373907455,-155.26497403146385,47.396291630635574,-204.64311988829914,58.05166445993317,-219.681074700439,59.20530444928809,-209.70299034076803,50.45784653208924,-169.9082998076096,37.93603960817075,-107.94348537998559,18.24310460098397,-31.95478451329897,-2.8463868141060504,48.634868833806536,-23.95577149937846,119.13645716149925,-40.925439915269436,171.01329088776606,-50.50659373308337,196.3370041048725,-53.99281871210743,194.90844051477362,-49.64233078359078,171.32248297385667,-40.32662965234744,132.56435663655705,-28.868664091919587,90.8060476007528,-17.704546633704958,53.23069849946992,-9.067469075026388,25.918313762686726,-3.5532161468136625,9.541052755261239,-0.7455523020653944,2.1175397013476123,-57.71864575775363,17.28147083576506,-172.45992815210494,38.048161293580776,-283.0686325656879,49.973410745347344,-372.0342516633013,63.14783956576618,-399.7613796831809,64.40114850356703,-382.19984008225737,54.26102383286226,-309.25200203075633,41.392489045857026,-196.76177850421257,19.434369135130154,-57.867033336422274,-3.113436514143022,88.55695425735618,-26.266817493778298,217.1758785884401,-44.64354055883439,311.2963900862864,-54.70001357568705,357.72941055721,-58.68938474373469,354.91073068661456,-53.81701354884506,311.8940584947133,-43.52045190302168,241.3606934430477,-31.095505529270962,165.14060627623167,-18.854768157200173,96.76760378260147,-9.599531981466018,47.062186359972365,-3.64355575368665,17.333617462715843,-0.6958931935539702,3.8953617812899046,11.865965922924442,-0.047182256829281316,-55.9976567987792,0.5560752072503191,-91.36805639128063,-2.40110971840165,-119.20989431226599,-0.4954168149047405,-128.67671130102633,-0.5203173192048003,-122.87407825335481,-1.1518083552845606,-99.44265664749791,-0.40882178426214894,-63.15996061112738,-0.5994657388491135,-18.453781340848263,-0.14549158726052283,28.674850613030625,-0.2073554043129364,70.05064893324746,0.12659485107219434,100.36835689308906,0.5427234448860151,115.17981886211828,0.43909218917632115,114.1886441915433,0.6697417561855321,100.25573933768169,0.8494563506230359,77.48389549175978,0.7875203638773425,52.85129163768039,0.8495628731406233,30.822972175496595,0.5803135929533729,14.933597611774806,0.40108940422074196,5.431578244287351,0.22479894584919233,1.1254357400260995,-23.999999999999943,6.67032204596957e-14,1.245406167676584e-13,1.4703831719607764e-13,2.5632650422903316e-13,2.1125691421248602e-13,3.014305387567766e-13,2.5312420566727674e-13,3.263294721136611e-13,2.705119068247448e-13,3.0616848128832963e-13,2.6452732877735657e-13,2.513171654396122e-13,2.384625893321381e-13,1.7188502873295985e-13,1.992919679733673e-13,7.237692304769979e-14,1.566343367477935e-13,-3.181994344332885e-14,1.1841869015096767e-13,-1.2068261501707508e-13,8.829555432128558e-14,-1.8058564072506982e-13,6.682713886443883e-14,-2.0745844624845483e-13,5.6610293783247607e-14,-2.0269973181573283e-13,6.458216506803031e-14,-1.711473367247439e-13,9.522438100091545e-14,-1.1813075741260172e-13,1.407680983530586e-13,-6.384802726290595e-14,1.762883615109664e-13,-2.1819592555661978e-14,1.8925477518271193e-13,5.925989391252889e-15,2.007038813065584e-13,2.897604295251666e-14,2.2096332135585036e-13,3.863827871501308e-14
-34.64402536047812,-11.455828502131084,-70.90937551354654,-25.0698630587689,-119.17564526974192,-29.47546044254167,-149.5403766613505,-40.11408522489941,-164.0019461569772,-39.697516517934396,-156.9189884886608,-34.12792060405608,-125.6035006489732,-25.43011247883094,-80.1579125596776,-12.357569247446465,-23.22714272655892,2.3768986782776476,37.68232449705663,16.7064658544094,90.13966134895472,28.044158579005032,128.0525023136314,34.37845067715536,147.63476573934634,36.63633847391653,145.6458244280552,33.727873699957854,127.00120672016247,26.80510508324922,98.01002059853704,19.26752797265695,66.00116746292429,11.385826318557724,38.10256176425981,5.699041612203609,17.973730500525612,1.97197656276801,6.338839482209682,0.2786925706373274,1.2463085405314185,-43.65508509001885,-21.883528117995493,-106.0223257106916,-47.992420691067224,-178.15576337638888,-57.605597033945706,-223.45292499863635,-77.24404507771712,-245.11401079019896,-77.06718475860526,-234.65305294792665,-65.6134061974738,-187.61185675015616,-48.91142146917369,-119.70506008797273,-23.86768099525287,-34.74561129590767,4.971174178273401,56.62800460153434,32.71874124370784,134.79714863238578,54.5031002797497,191.6097156329819,66.94301369210436,220.81784128048912,71.04471836532372,217.69378643350097,65.10791990238272,189.8294077728319,51.66733924608743,146.39455701293298,36.717589073923634,98.43779421445157,21.496087103509815,56.76111501051328,10.55916794851428,26.720009139493072,3.4478331761224412,9.336195474832389,0.30860015629065735,1.7901158571445703,10.9540327235926,-12.205775071635719,-59.14681578797914,-25.627659581232162,-98.6499161887821,-32.787683480231934,-126.12086851579656,-42.12729794633168,-137.69461633379393,-42.16052720688282,-131.0725968691951,-36.32322106512736,-105.59638403508261,-26.86435125092388,-67.29977783294687,-13.348087894797008,-19.736591961968596,2.4352601845944206,30.959432837633678,17.606790188686183,75.057175830335,29.45364019320936,106.9498294722454,36.57652070669936,123.18213019711835,38.716001556101666,121.92180484570903,35.729153727324395,106.59585684874544,28.6341918354506,82.51404641448742,20.56949197089059,55.89153183523403,12.356936788229584,32.59883802438832,6.253688977619723,15.614751231316143,2.197931304960789,5.59984406341373,0.36499607662825584,1.2282932057109928,-23.999999999999943,6.67032204596957e-14,1.245406167676584e-13,1.4703831719607764e-13,2.5632650422903316e-13,2.1125691421248602e-13,3.014305387567766e-13,2.5312420566727674e-13,3.263294721136611e-13,2.705119068247448e-13,3.0616848128832963e-13,2.6452732877735657e-13,2.513171654396122e-13,2.384625893321381e-13,1.7188502873295985e-13,1.992919679733673e-13,7.237692304769979e-14,1.566343367477935e-13,-3.181994344332885e-14,1.1841869015096767e-13,-1.2068261501707508e-13,8.829555432128558e-14,-1.8058564072506982e-13,6.682713886443883e-14,-2.0745844624845483e-13,5.6610293783247607e-14,-2.0269973181573283e-13,6.458216506803031e-14,-1.711473367247439e-13,9.522438100091545e-14,-1.1813075741260172e-13,1.407680983530586e-13,-6.384802726290595e-14,1.762883615109664e-13,-2.1819592555661978e-14,1.8925477518271193e-13,5.925989391252889e-15,2.007038813065584e-13,2.897604295251666e-14,2.2096332135585036e-13,3.863827871501308e-14
-12.8408798564239,0.28061249825016815,34.53958673182587,0.5014708081103845,55.62039081765273,-4.969446745735228,74.2323459208757,-1.9825984430257437,78.5276272318532,-4.258158146091042,76.03439069995665,-2.200088227442309,60.71875268142746,-2.507544744895987,39.566486726374144,-0.9287392384534298,11.154011893362446,-0.040018736112625616,-16.73041469228135,1.120684733551886,-43.03143676723125,2.2679701183205205,-60.92058236547474,2.5937212656225896,-70.73509764312975,3.174570843050211,-69.86954329593138,2.4648930605116908,-61.86642773263714,2.680467284118004,-47.925175233720154,1.5805807581186182,-33.10138005405231,1.3242023376606253,-19.54989100186437,0.6844103658638561,-9.639722620149223,0.34437020746937497,-3.618374154984058,0.06864000124231896,-0.8646672859142038,-7.373772668554193,-7.042485047837325,69.15506139640723,-16.07435304630718,111.4207664549849,-32.68612322382902,147.70369200964242,-31.830862092875503,156.733241886693,-36.026054625527,151.91180825908125,-29.261985522980872,121.3095912618849,-22.85458140732963,78.99340024024893,-10.966951673594105,21.967438547734652,1.1657514308983206,-33.65718337265655,13.175615590458815,-86.07869507303425,23.550543243862016,-121.91206647640857,29.107204138292747,-141.37552622265565,31.657173140172276,-139.7247484636391,28.691780380591236,-123.380651022803,24.735855704871696,-95.55864958100645,17.445017364700664,-65.75396146106594,11.534350768324517,-38.70702452571988,6.196187863254168,-18.977202808809817,2.680066859454754,-7.113832298484459,0.7538501521869683,-1.7316860873086792,30.493031677294972,5.976636653380869,36.22137442212855,13.501150573668708,58.34698636760835,16.777449444603935,77.41208407735694,20.865011808112694,82.05163764190524,20.73229746518012,79.6756407205312,18.74776890314963,63.40184153192701,13.14230709668623,41.23318763587248,6.727863586884603,11.550010932426016,-1.4256482053155042,-17.892348243414634,-8.996776746312383,-45.16715233898161,-14.62903580786098,-64.02951500835314,-18.682889318221676,-74.21398756343827,-19.363941150848486,-73.1652181324506,-17.981611558323188,-64.64132672240143,-14.201711609412401,-49.91560447532547,-10.15814965538049,-34.23581762017737,-6.0207792630334565,-20.07231029886038,-2.8892151773384724,-9.803067017195826,-1.0419590591167078,-3.613093428903183,-0.17876799172363436,-0.8363541589856663,-23.999999999999943,6.67032204596957e-14,1.245406167676584e-13,1.4703831719607764e-13,2.5632650422903316e-13,2.1125691421248602e-13,3.014305387567766e-13,2.5312420566727674e-13,3.263294721136611e-13,2.705119068247448e-13,3.0616848128832963e-13,2.6452732877735657e-13,2.513171654396122e-13,2.384625893321381e-13,1.7188502873295985e-13,1.992919679733673e-13,7.237692304769979e-14,1.566343367477935e-13,-3.181994344332885e-14,1.1841869015096767e-13,-1.2068261501707508e-13,8.829555432128558e-14,-1.8058564072506982e-13,6.682713886443883e-14,-2.0745844624845483e-13,5.6610293783247607e-14,-2.0269973181573283e-13,6.458216506803031e-14,-1.711473367247439e-13,9.522438100091545e-14,-1.1813075741260172e-13,1.407680983530586e-13,-6.384802726290595e-14,1.762883615109664e-13,-2.1819592555661978e-14,1.8925477518271193e-13,5.925989391252889e-15,2.007038813065584e-13,2.897604295251666e-14,2.2096332135585036e-13,3.863827871501308e-14
-24.6726215541879,16.814402197810274,-22.519157544436606,36.700026910568376,-33.08665854794263,55.52176932166965,-48.78038813617218,63.23986301969791,-52.371760007200336,64.92111894063541,-47.36062173903998,56.81683118822,-39.66776006844495,40.910772743841925,-25.206636888967918,21.148814894002065,-7.423718383923886,-3.0399129376366196,10.354960921096644,-26.11573864231887,27.755807695046972,-44.17450735892106,39.49757331602493,-56.0249225019931,44.91627861628658,-59.08622820825267,45.31041861741872,-54.711453811445836,39.90350822004194,-45.00156167017626,30.904418581354864,-32.26235799167411,21.630318233793343,-20.243185449909625,12.857470447888485,-10.597094271342293,6.436364577497009,-4.292158107319513,2.299432002717632,-1.0744782662367782,0.47277163123485577,-32.31933481016613,45.04033529440388,-51.669687178385814,98.52278066599834,-78.07915338986972,145.91276072239447,-111.26846806142781,167.74007646847198,-119.733478661419,172.45946307404054,-109.56598876002226,150.47595842487883,-91.2987841964282,108.87080991331193,-57.743760762118576,55.30565574945274,-17.065550603055605,-8.741394834836038,24.43663175716833,-69.86980445172105,63.74261470300987,-118.21954515896218,90.99776820728867,-149.14613918032404,103.7410864650887,-157.40567311660232,104.28137583059697,-145.29622090938034,91.58138198443494,-118.8703689726097,70.96927244071607,-84.72007296738082,49.22670101963504,-52.60299502016862,29.188162677131626,-27.044919235501467,14.499441031323775,-10.85034471068179,5.253263543322755,-2.560361758192811,1.2265067471039741,10.946317677565535,29.110235699935444,-57.88654077264279,64.1113064214979,-94.02222062341608,91.31282062386519,-124.28750817864734,106.7739858079234,-134.96590271026494,109.77817031671252,-126.56449757821584,95.42628394898408,-103.72391994486343,69.58104453176355,-65.88868686517948,34.955909505736365,-19.10341909707867,-5.71780054480044,28.645767841239373,-44.58449861198907,72.6782718637623,-75.48116780101697,103.76755924457112,-94.73727275585145,119.05244058934628,-100.25905620452073,118.77021552104443,-92.43821236829586,104.15529386496785,-75.38914556448215,80.89099561359198,-53.8711647845645,55.463770389413234,-33.25627463685631,32.716175611062695,-16.99677937783543,16.063193207606343,-6.731200378998755,5.959161455816945,-1.537183837729182,1.3835328825787698,-23.999999999999943,6.67032204596957e-14,1.245406167676584e-13,1.4703831719607764e-13,2.5632650422903316e-13,2.1125691421248602e-13,3.014305387567766e-13,2.5312420566727674e-13,3.263294721136611e-13,2.705119068247448e-13,3.0616848128832963e-13,2.6452732877735657e-13,2.513171654396122e-13,2.384625893321381e-13,1.7188502873295985e-13,1.992919679733673e-13,7.237692304769979e-14,1.566343367477935e-13,-3.181994344332885e-14,1.1841869015096767e-13,-1.2068261501707508e-13,8.829555432128558e-14,-1.8058564072506982e-13,6.682713886443883e-14,-2.0745844624845483e-13,5.6610293783247607e-14,-2.0269973181573283e-13,6.458216506803031e-14,-1.711473367247439e-13,9.522438100091545e-14,-1.1813075741260172e-13,1.407680983530586e-13,-6.384802726290595e-14,1.762883615109664e-13,-2.1819592555661978e-14,1.8925477518271193e-13,5.925989391252889e-15,2.007038813065584e-13,2.897604295251666e-14,2.2096332135585036e-13,3.863827871501308e-14
```

Comment: paste your csv rows as text, not as image

Comment: as i mentioned in the question, it is quite long (would not be readable), and I could not get it to reproduce with fewer columns

Comment: you have to provide otherwise we can't reproduce your error

Comment: okay its better than expected, i hope the repro is possible now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is problem in csv header, because missing 4 last values 160-163.

Solution is create default columns names by parameters `header=None` and `skiprows=1` for avoid convert csv header to first row of `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.max_columns = 20

temp=u"""0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159
-28.72466306892318e12,16.966026399304525,-42.87239163479887,37.06969272107673,-74.2601964196411,57.915233690916786,-89.63410196434016,64.41009089917166,-98.67490642089729,67.1343290789727,-95.55111417210443,58.013282233594246,-76.32484819818251,42.11132556642663,-48.524290504722494,21.526589964168203,-13.8581233306059,-3.3490646092526433,22.84198653097978,-27.060896358727,54.382255845878014,-45.673473909527225,77.50880722737743,-57.791741228592976,89.56781809792449,-60.99336804220146,88.16348841894312,-56.11574199299081,76.86514428022184,-46.16717828337371,59.47716972301922,-32.752475257286164,39.820088490713246,-20.495941260416675,22.99935074984098,-10.523079594855439,10.88663389926389,-4.196380698527703,4.000935028546149,-0.9772293254528972,0.8609574288131829,-46.57054283319171,19.173016773335288,-122.4805546477765,41.742910475315824,-208.91998901446402,68.9664104196525,-257.479377604769,74.1446030525972,-282.24875512874866,77.90373111349169,-271.9070079387826,67.31928472555192,-217.9639123101401,48.55696873721421,-138.56835354764408,25.361218668551334,-39.98915690908285,-3.6731602010503646,64.7235138574192,-31.259854021448785,154.94427632476325,-52.533782321163265,221.0576060603368,-66.88535164334371,254.96243683781972,-70.60071237115383,251.5503449550602,-64.87873370201224,219.6325271034961,-53.756735801722286,169.89294378572342,-38.174554507004174,114.44452853083385,-24.221894115553884,66.24186369357932,-12.489356301147113,31.509425779676448,-5.011549296016099,11.523955561693546,-1.2324596975505553,2.3942274604386133,13.698544314233853,12.73370853971873,-52.86500337481437,29.570941419742685,-87.62956576633692,46.13278092029744,-111.67436913458086,50.51561043181823,-121.00678656606034,52.73871768373986,-116.34162689010873,45.990152440201086,-93.77626222289165,33.031020425879824,-59.46247366546009,17.13930792580037,-17.339720046909793,-2.5240093448743592,27.358558591981225,-21.200012975473076,66.19941324276897,-35.7192163946112,94.65397551469647,-45.43806304646717,108.9992926772042,-47.97784408098858,107.74571885528185,-44.16805179745866,94.46496252194154,-36.43785989536876,72.9893490627619,-25.982707486226108,49.579463942266266,-16.362206532868928,28.80367841198022,-8.45589399968555,13.867311815346214,-3.4405875266757437,5.10296002559008,-0.8957867120997663,1.082578692873228,-23.999999999999943,6.67032204596957e-14,1.245406167676584e-13,1.4703831719607764e-13,2.5632650422903316e-13,2.1125691421248602e-13,3.014305387567766e-13,2.5312420566727674e-13,3.263294721136611e-13,2.705119068247448e-13,3.0616848128832963e-13,2.6452732877735657e-13,2.513171654396122e-13,2.384625893321381e-13,1.7188502873295985e-13,1.992919679733673e-13,7.237692304769979e-14,1.566343367477935e-13,-3.181994344332885e-14,1.1841869015096767e-13,-1.2068261501707508e-13,8.829555432128558e-14,-1.8058564072506982e-13,6.682713886443883e-14,-2.0745844624845483e-13,5.6610293783247607e-14,-2.0269973181573283e-13,6.458216506803031e-14,-1.711473367247439e-13,9.522438100091545e-14,-1.1813075741260172e-13,1.407680983530586e-13,-6.384802726290595e-14,1.762883615109664e-13,-2.1819592555661978e-14,1.8925477518271193e-13,5.925989391252889e-15,2.007038813065584e-13,2.897604295251666e-14,2.2096332135585036e-13,3.863827871501308e-14
-21.413867228646293,-2.5282711935618956,-6.93084627003621,-5.011281934809228,-11.18544892521373,-13.82494999878299,-14.372899121058246,-11.704558468672218,-14.970243065475522,-14.073951582795912,-15.441519819745524,-11.04957060042677,-11.611656380494479,-8.886315160681761,-8.104091917250543,-4.1300354629158385,-1.8360509557227367,0.3317104638105255,3.239224351426863,5.111004105366378,8.72047049244835,8.93742416563495,11.876672813644635,11.264631735274337,14.111682201447774,12.148667163684236,13.691806605063794,10.933643879890152,12.163598127441935,9.601211444327774,9.335226248842032,6.633907879820257,6.456949359407382,4.532033345632565,3.7030605445882094,2.366556112221847,1.7629581082433585,1.052957855574088,0.6730330611544868,0.29518625569391177,0.13194177349972525,-22.528399330936658,-10.218402616297713,-4.841101019146182,-21.25295346847763,-7.706372249262545,-42.27447847181991,-9.758007395302544,-41.61013373069367,-9.993084664686297,-46.74327139232265,-10.974479508239385,-38.199306394971465,-7.80494467584213,-29.854035615932748,-5.78695614348123,-14.004964936216076,-1.1890878347360148,1.503988496991579,2.096362889577231,17.63817487718735,6.05890636045365,30.621073579140752,7.912624038640294,38.396988470145736,9.816518143261789,41.16096191617698,9.245731854057963,37.56080833989963,8.43976069439306,32.01753319226937,6.512702083133027,22.555957617105854,4.498060929047554,14.767180923240758,2.636319396719282,7.776400456117172,1.294125481417865,3.3313747492173245,0.49160806311104105,0.877104013716125,0.1297128903509163,33.784476973265065,-7.484384792088839,46.470200065782855,-14.530635628256524,75.92586657472982,-23.336327003383527,100.23164849210958,-25.809578434144882,107.44090289970589,-27.413430060957342,102.19849070583751,-23.343303094753438,83.65110890217584,-17.557349687746335,52.725271313432636,-8.486447137904806,16.060518010495674,1.1757650556959078,-23.350614386598963,10.879400186469855,-57.55346243162423,18.50569211371895,-83.25475720762397,23.196146642573286,-95.42059935070722,24.717891750692065,-95.18353525298454,22.723895459431446,-83.854396011233,18.8174210538905,-65.25258471631356,13.435649100641283,-45.054078634228105,8.466954555817326,-26.69324356618218,4.40121621281668,-13.216509648249286,1.7749897729440731,-5.041643821943503,0.466433937508152,-1.2130589071662057,-23.999999999999943,6.67032204596957e-14,1.245406167676584e-13,1.4703831719607764e-13,2.5632650422903316e-13,2.1125691421248602e-13,3.014305387567766e-13,2.5312420566727674e-13,3.263294721136611e-13,2.705119068247448e-13,3.0616848128832963e-13,2.6452732877735657e-13,2.513171654396122e-13,2.384625893321381e-13,1.7188502873295985e-13,1.992919679733673e-13,7.237692304769979e-14,1.566343367477935e-13,-3.181994344332885e-14,1.1841869015096767e-13,-1.2068261501707508e-13,8.829555432128558e-14,-1.8058564072506982e-13,6.682713886443883e-14,-2.0745844624845483e-13,5.6610293783247607e-14,-2.0269973181573283e-13,6.458216506803031e-14,-1.711473367247439e-13,9.522438100091545e-14,-1.1813075741260172e-13,1.407680983530586e-13,-6.384802726290595e-14,1.762883615109664e-13,-2.1819592555661978e-14,1.8925477518271193e-13,5.925989391252889e-15,2.007038813065584e-13,2.897604295251666e-14,2.2096332135585036e-13,3.863827871501308e-14
-12.125493312295697,-34.09794657251972,38.069088966261916,-76.20309075312167,65.78897044854793,-102.0312361515325,80.60529297455379,-123.58636739296253,88.64140073901794,-126.40928586763523,84.81641277200197,-109.63248775411394,68.54114006197086,-80.27814316518379,43.318317313309386,-39.87167341087051,12.611565462783032,7.0155868493336575,-19.883558562374986,51.973657170324984,-48.28683472152177,87.54987882013181,-69.01998092472982,109.2599415624865,-79.60448405719227,115.83298874020483,-78.71836229433853,106.57679185027004,-68.79050121330484,86.29487343013159,-53.38432345324279,61.64555309782151,-36.03045840834482,37.49303117734715,-21.01718682371514,18.955157795848468,-10.129766845241473,7.25348156793155,-3.8057557863291893,1.509289022457166,-0.8454823358547632,9.382804542167415,-54.310278558612865,149.97685399303987,-121.54251408987733,254.68351992876472,-161.3999693575505,318.45177720345674,-196.1709050320829,347.7705265120273,-200.41097100870275,332.8017843795614,-174.06031666628934,269.1226025368736,-127.81311629765261,170.66817958195784,-63.0631956261192,49.95107674053664,10.853706988213343,-77.40961558167837,82.08773755730195,-188.9848776941043,138.74523792339494,-270.4251044748159,173.01988153330134,-311.7271073546612,183.62243791083392,-308.78676820608877,169.13719986322485,-270.4184162059884,137.0398336527759,-210.07068616916618,98.18901242285897,-142.63369353435172,59.74236147974591,-83.56976149062885,30.456934784249782,-40.49013423793536,11.720249947109785,-15.173528851765308,2.6066725925994914,-3.4694316211792855,39.946378152881685,-14.068748243927935,79.15761667238796,-30.16212888970618,134.43889210146241,-42.27956245431031,168.0057401214446,-49.70549302444846,183.39491677651472,-51.427639882629734,175.32283204020933,-44.20346376023586,141.63704567916832,-32.58383518672739,90.05011333691964,-16.10283543999799,26.404326126748916,2.7105516186781684,-40.638114958099465,20.910683947576747,-99.5253277233919,35.391033292956514,-142.43075302545498,44.13943552320413,-164.19007623283915,46.94194756745503,-162.64579512894062,43.04770692440849,-142.51868794018966,35.06481791322439,-110.81735779544111,24.95466533237414,-75.29241041455396,15.311034651748727,-44.20619053147193,7.76488334934033,-21.461113179911518,3.026243575741641,-8.01698884896578,0.6707031900634406,-1.8150452311083567,-23.999999999999943,6.67032204596957e-14,1.245406167676584e-13,1.4703831719607764e-13,2.5632650422903316e-13,2.1125691421248602e-13,3.014305387567766e-13,2.5312420566727674e-13,3.263294721136611e-13,2.705119068247448e-13,3.0616848128832963e-13,2.6452732877735657e-13,2.513171654396122e-13,2.384625893321381e-13,1.7188502873295985e-13,1.992919679733673e-13,7.237692304769979e-14,1.566343367477935e-13,-3.181994344332885e-14,1.1841869015096767e-13,-1.2068261501707508e-13,8.829555432128558e-14,-1.8058564072506982e-13,6.682713886443883e-14,-2.0745844624845483e-13,5.6610293783247607e-14,-2.0269973181573283e-13,6.458216506803031e-14,-1.711473367247439e-13,9.522438100091545e-14,-1.1813075741260172e-13,1.407680983530586e-13,-6.384802726290595e-14,1.762883615109664e-13,-2.1819592555661978e-14,1.8925477518271193e-13,5.925989391252889e-15,2.007038813065584e-13,2.897604295251666e-14,2.2096332135585036e-13,3.863827871501308e-14
-12.443814181545712,-0.779742972501207,35.46271925365665,-1.0713430959730332,55.59917209577768,-4.444180728061166,76.53237133069723,-2.699100450821645,80.65274565576696,-3.48717315322838,78.67439029670224,-2.7334248863918305,62.57027352823641,-2.012683421001301,40.50564575992955,-1.2035773454143732,11.156204639891412,0.1297963377275013,-18.252306120977018,1.0864210029004528,-44.95716203610979,2.1422192874341026,-63.66738815172255,2.784672171356919,-73.40861444337301,2.9880299805264823,-72.32248999279741,2.6160937678994527,-63.778498272512984,2.4457388281902004,-48.75587932293529,1.6428876390519527,-33.384312625308034,1.2371619166217547,-19.19628833109976,0.6524063873151025,-9.176539186198763,0.3119835777933488,-3.256911223384156,0.09381516097267666,-0.6533186760152704,6.175374320669617,-1.659920482536208,132.94673619292143,-1.9511830486682329,215.75094403240672,-8.041250759613808,285.477407375372,-4.860132827761133,305.6340017284426,-5.677340146877335,294.1483114744587,-5.5808220715389165,236.7718618626109,-3.41269236482024,151.43568310980984,-2.486701247900934,43.69546338571588,0.13246340970364748,-67.98123130113659,1.7210823564717816,-167.18909719052022,3.400681798010776,-238.7727488210806,4.954850991377992,-274.86282648896105,4.9606947640803245,-272.10907318018104,4.7843092617082075,-239.4416393098253,4.504017767971821,-184.86197052726416,3.3314471952707554,-126.48988415766692,2.6150911146171896,-73.81787853280058,1.4782070275930301,-35.80516462435737,0.7925874778703128,-13.122624918944148,0.29460979190553943,-2.8816444331209183,36.287274217602864,7.533884887056847,61.37696102981825,16.393879773079995,99.6941384443596,24.766924121123175,130.33540857258927,28.911567002412838,140.26158950040542,29.529211488045167,134.60583190274465,25.642931314092646,108.7430668567604,19.180126647727302,69.26708954057187,9.18162907187632,20.062629685678,-1.1881098477427734,-31.18690344279684,-11.672572408405792,-76.553804824702,-20.205484860697826,-109.44074080626666,-25.217831200652334,-125.9128471533268,-26.873839993904124,-124.82921995434799,-24.92650923766527,-109.59478404167643,-20.47867178278849,-84.75999861806214,-14.781030514709872,-57.928619836170874,-9.247405177923108,-33.80675081878248,-4.940421623159597,-16.384713870015812,-2.017148181816816,-6.065107305744551,-0.5911294706244511,-1.3704990818520457,-23.999999999999943,6.67032204596957e-14,1.245406167676584e-13,1.4703831719607764e-13,2.5632650422903316e-13,2.1125691421248602e-13,3.014305387567766e-13,2.5312420566727674e-13,3.263294721136611e-13,2.705119068247448e-13,3.0616848128832963e-13,2.6452732877735657e-13,2.513171654396122e-13,2.384625893321381e-13,1.7188502873295985e-13,1.992919679733673e-13,7.237692304769979e-14,1.566343367477935e-13,-3.181994344332885e-14,1.1841869015096767e-13,-1.2068261501707508e-13,8.829555432128558e-14,-1.8058564072506982e-13,6.682713886443883e-14,-2.0745844624845483e-13,5.6610293783247607e-14,-2.0269973181573283e-13,6.458216506803031e-14,-1.711473367247439e-13,9.522438100091545e-14,-1.1813075741260172e-13,1.407680983530586e-13,-6.384802726290595e-14,1.762883615109664e-13,-2.1819592555661978e-14,1.8925477518271193e-13,5.925989391252889e-15,2.007038813065584e-13,2.897604295251666e-14,2.2096332135585036e-13,3.863827871501308e-14
-39.754794743744924,15.78882434231351,-94.72703002814102,34.90634373907455,-155.26497403146385,47.396291630635574,-204.64311988829914,58.05166445993317,-219.681074700439,59.20530444928809,-209.70299034076803,50.45784653208924,-169.9082998076096,37.93603960817075,-107.94348537998559,18.24310460098397,-31.95478451329897,-2.8463868141060504,48.634868833806536,-23.95577149937846,119.13645716149925,-40.925439915269436,171.01329088776606,-50.50659373308337,196.3370041048725,-53.99281871210743,194.90844051477362,-49.64233078359078,171.32248297385667,-40.32662965234744,132.56435663655705,-28.868664091919587,90.8060476007528,-17.704546633704958,53.23069849946992,-9.067469075026388,25.918313762686726,-3.5532161468136625,9.541052755261239,-0.7455523020653944,2.1175397013476123,-57.71864575775363,17.28147083576506,-172.45992815210494,38.048161293580776,-283.0686325656879,49.973410745347344,-372.0342516633013,63.14783956576618,-399.7613796831809,64.40114850356703,-382.19984008225737,54.26102383286226,-309.25200203075633,41.392489045857026,-196.76177850421257,19.434369135130154,-57.867033336422274,-3.113436514143022,88.55695425735618,-26.266817493778298,217.1758785884401,-44.64354055883439,311.2963900862864,-54.70001357568705,357.72941055721,-58.68938474373469,354.91073068661456,-53.81701354884506,311.8940584947133,-43.52045190302168,241.3606934430477,-31.095505529270962,165.14060627623167,-18.854768157200173,96.76760378260147,-9.599531981466018,47.062186359972365,-3.64355575368665,17.333617462715843,-0.6958931935539702,3.8953617812899046,11.865965922924442,-0.047182256829281316,-55.9976567987792,0.5560752072503191,-91.36805639128063,-2.40110971840165,-119.20989431226599,-0.4954168149047405,-128.67671130102633,-0.5203173192048003,-122.87407825335481,-1.1518083552845606,-99.44265664749791,-0.40882178426214894,-63.15996061112738,-0.5994657388491135,-18.453781340848263,-0.14549158726052283,28.674850613030625,-0.2073554043129364,70.05064893324746,0.12659485107219434,100.36835689308906,0.5427234448860151,115.17981886211828,0.43909218917632115,114.1886441915433,0.6697417561855321,100.25573933768169,0.8494563506230359,77.48389549175978,0.7875203638773425,52.85129163768039,0.8495628731406233,30.822972175496595,0.5803135929533729,14.933597611774806,0.40108940422074196,5.431578244287351,0.22479894584919233,1.1254357400260995,-23.999999999999943,6.67032204596957e-14,1.245406167676584e-13,1.4703831719607764e-13,2.5632650422903316e-13,2.1125691421248602e-13,3.014305387567766e-13,2.5312420566727674e-13,3.263294721136611e-13,2.705119068247448e-13,3.0616848128832963e-13,2.6452732877735657e-13,2.513171654396122e-13,2.384625893321381e-13,1.7188502873295985e-13,1.992919679733673e-13,7.237692304769979e-14,1.566343367477935e-13,-3.181994344332885e-14,1.1841869015096767e-13,-1.2068261501707508e-13,8.829555432128558e-14,-1.8058564072506982e-13,6.682713886443883e-14,-2.0745844624845483e-13,5.6610293783247607e-14,-2.0269973181573283e-13,6.458216506803031e-14,-1.711473367247439e-13,9.522438100091545e-14,-1.1813075741260172e-13,1.407680983530586e-13,-6.384802726290595e-14,1.762883615109664e-13,-2.1819592555661978e-14,1.8925477518271193e-13,5.925989391252889e-15,2.007038813065584e-13,2.897604295251666e-14,2.2096332135585036e-13,3.863827871501308e-14
-34.64402536047812,-11.455828502131084,-70.90937551354654,-25.0698630587689,-119.17564526974192,-29.47546044254167,-149.5403766613505,-40.11408522489941,-164.0019461569772,-39.697516517934396,-156.9189884886608,-34.12792060405608,-125.6035006489732,-25.43011247883094,-80.1579125596776,-12.357569247446465,-23.22714272655892,2.3768986782776476,37.68232449705663,16.7064658544094,90.13966134895472,28.044158579005032,128.0525023136314,34.37845067715536,147.63476573934634,36.63633847391653,145.6458244280552,33.727873699957854,127.00120672016247,26.80510508324922,98.01002059853704,19.26752797265695,66.00116746292429,11.385826318557724,38.10256176425981,5.699041612203609,17.973730500525612,1.97197656276801,6.338839482209682,0.2786925706373274,1.2463085405314185,-43.65508509001885,-21.883528117995493,-106.0223257106916,-47.992420691067224,-178.15576337638888,-57.605597033945706,-223.45292499863635,-77.24404507771712,-245.11401079019896,-77.06718475860526,-234.65305294792665,-65.6134061974738,-187.61185675015616,-48.91142146917369,-119.70506008797273,-23.86768099525287,-34.74561129590767,4.971174178273401,56.62800460153434,32.71874124370784,134.79714863238578,54.5031002797497,191.6097156329819,66.94301369210436,220.81784128048912,71.04471836532372,217.69378643350097,65.10791990238272,189.8294077728319,51.66733924608743,146.39455701293298,36.717589073923634,98.43779421445157,21.496087103509815,56.76111501051328,10.55916794851428,26.720009139493072,3.4478331761224412,9.336195474832389,0.30860015629065735,1.7901158571445703,10.9540327235926,-12.205775071635719,-59.14681578797914,-25.627659581232162,-98.6499161887821,-32.787683480231934,-126.12086851579656,-42.12729794633168,-137.69461633379393,-42.16052720688282,-131.0725968691951,-36.32322106512736,-105.59638403508261,-26.86435125092388,-67.29977783294687,-13.348087894797008,-19.736591961968596,2.4352601845944206,30.959432837633678,17.606790188686183,75.057175830335,29.45364019320936,106.9498294722454,36.57652070669936,123.18213019711835,38.716001556101666,121.92180484570903,35.729153727324395,106.59585684874544,28.6341918354506,82.51404641448742,20.56949197089059,55.89153183523403,12.356936788229584,32.59883802438832,6.253688977619723,15.614751231316143,2.197931304960789,5.59984406341373,0.36499607662825584,1.2282932057109928,-23.999999999999943,6.67032204596957e-14,1.245406167676584e-13,1.4703831719607764e-13,2.5632650422903316e-13,2.1125691421248602e-13,3.014305387567766e-13,2.5312420566727674e-13,3.263294721136611e-13,2.705119068247448e-13,3.0616848128832963e-13,2.6452732877735657e-13,2.513171654396122e-13,2.384625893321381e-13,1.7188502873295985e-13,1.992919679733673e-13,7.237692304769979e-14,1.566343367477935e-13,-3.181994344332885e-14,1.1841869015096767e-13,-1.2068261501707508e-13,8.829555432128558e-14,-1.8058564072506982e-13,6.682713886443883e-14,-2.0745844624845483e-13,5.6610293783247607e-14,-2.0269973181573283e-13,6.458216506803031e-14,-1.711473367247439e-13,9.522438100091545e-14,-1.1813075741260172e-13,1.407680983530586e-13,-6.384802726290595e-14,1.762883615109664e-13,-2.1819592555661978e-14,1.8925477518271193e-13,5.925989391252889e-15,2.007038813065584e-13,2.897604295251666e-14,2.2096332135585036e-13,3.863827871501308e-14
-12.8408798564239,0.28061249825016815,34.53958673182587,0.5014708081103845,55.62039081765273,-4.969446745735228,74.2323459208757,-1.9825984430257437,78.5276272318532,-4.258158146091042,76.03439069995665,-2.200088227442309,60.71875268142746,-2.507544744895987,39.566486726374144,-0.9287392384534298,11.154011893362446,-0.040018736112625616,-16.73041469228135,1.120684733551886,-43.03143676723125,2.2679701183205205,-60.92058236547474,2.5937212656225896,-70.73509764312975,3.174570843050211,-69.86954329593138,2.4648930605116908,-61.86642773263714,2.680467284118004,-47.925175233720154,1.5805807581186182,-33.10138005405231,1.3242023376606253,-19.54989100186437,0.6844103658638561,-9.639722620149223,0.34437020746937497,-3.618374154984058,0.06864000124231896,-0.8646672859142038,-7.373772668554193,-7.042485047837325,69.15506139640723,-16.07435304630718,111.4207664549849,-32.68612322382902,147.70369200964242,-31.830862092875503,156.733241886693,-36.026054625527,151.91180825908125,-29.261985522980872,121.3095912618849,-22.85458140732963,78.99340024024893,-10.966951673594105,21.967438547734652,1.1657514308983206,-33.65718337265655,13.175615590458815,-86.07869507303425,23.550543243862016,-121.91206647640857,29.107204138292747,-141.37552622265565,31.657173140172276,-139.7247484636391,28.691780380591236,-123.380651022803,24.735855704871696,-95.55864958100645,17.445017364700664,-65.75396146106594,11.534350768324517,-38.70702452571988,6.196187863254168,-18.977202808809817,2.680066859454754,-7.113832298484459,0.7538501521869683,-1.7316860873086792,30.493031677294972,5.976636653380869,36.22137442212855,13.501150573668708,58.34698636760835,16.777449444603935,77.41208407735694,20.865011808112694,82.05163764190524,20.73229746518012,79.6756407205312,18.74776890314963,63.40184153192701,13.14230709668623,41.23318763587248,6.727863586884603,11.550010932426016,-1.4256482053155042,-17.892348243414634,-8.996776746312383,-45.16715233898161,-14.62903580786098,-64.02951500835314,-18.682889318221676,-74.21398756343827,-19.363941150848486,-73.1652181324506,-17.981611558323188,-64.64132672240143,-14.201711609412401,-49.91560447532547,-10.15814965538049,-34.23581762017737,-6.0207792630334565,-20.07231029886038,-2.8892151773384724,-9.803067017195826,-1.0419590591167078,-3.613093428903183,-0.17876799172363436,-0.8363541589856663,-23.999999999999943,6.67032204596957e-14,1.245406167676584e-13,1.4703831719607764e-13,2.5632650422903316e-13,2.1125691421248602e-13,3.014305387567766e-13,2.5312420566727674e-13,3.263294721136611e-13,2.705119068247448e-13,3.0616848128832963e-13,2.6452732877735657e-13,2.513171654396122e-13,2.384625893321381e-13,1.7188502873295985e-13,1.992919679733673e-13,7.237692304769979e-14,1.566343367477935e-13,-3.181994344332885e-14,1.1841869015096767e-13,-1.2068261501707508e-13,8.829555432128558e-14,-1.8058564072506982e-13,6.682713886443883e-14,-2.0745844624845483e-13,5.6610293783247607e-14,-2.0269973181573283e-13,6.458216506803031e-14,-1.711473367247439e-13,9.522438100091545e-14,-1.1813075741260172e-13,1.407680983530586e-13,-6.384802726290595e-14,1.762883615109664e-13,-2.1819592555661978e-14,1.8925477518271193e-13,5.925989391252889e-15,2.007038813065584e-13,2.897604295251666e-14,2.2096332135585036e-13,3.863827871501308e-14
-24.6726215541879,16.814402197810274,-22.519157544436606,36.700026910568376,-33.08665854794263,55.52176932166965,-48.78038813617218,63.23986301969791,-52.371760007200336,64.92111894063541,-47.36062173903998,56.81683118822,-39.66776006844495,40.910772743841925,-25.206636888967918,21.148814894002065,-7.423718383923886,-3.0399129376366196,10.354960921096644,-26.11573864231887,27.755807695046972,-44.17450735892106,39.49757331602493,-56.0249225019931,44.91627861628658,-59.08622820825267,45.31041861741872,-54.711453811445836,39.90350822004194,-45.00156167017626,30.904418581354864,-32.26235799167411,21.630318233793343,-20.243185449909625,12.857470447888485,-10.597094271342293,6.436364577497009,-4.292158107319513,2.299432002717632,-1.0744782662367782,0.47277163123485577,-32.31933481016613,45.04033529440388,-51.669687178385814,98.52278066599834,-78.07915338986972,145.91276072239447,-111.26846806142781,167.74007646847198,-119.733478661419,172.45946307404054,-109.56598876002226,150.47595842487883,-91.2987841964282,108.87080991331193,-57.743760762118576,55.30565574945274,-17.065550603055605,-8.741394834836038,24.43663175716833,-69.86980445172105,63.74261470300987,-118.21954515896218,90.99776820728867,-149.14613918032404,103.7410864650887,-157.40567311660232,104.28137583059697,-145.29622090938034,91.58138198443494,-118.8703689726097,70.96927244071607,-84.72007296738082,49.22670101963504,-52.60299502016862,29.188162677131626,-27.044919235501467,14.499441031323775,-10.85034471068179,5.253263543322755,-2.560361758192811,1.2265067471039741,10.946317677565535,29.110235699935444,-57.88654077264279,64.1113064214979,-94.02222062341608,91.31282062386519,-124.28750817864734,106.7739858079234,-134.96590271026494,109.77817031671252,-126.56449757821584,95.42628394898408,-103.72391994486343,69.58104453176355,-65.88868686517948,34.955909505736365,-19.10341909707867,-5.71780054480044,28.645767841239373,-44.58449861198907,72.6782718637623,-75.48116780101697,103.76755924457112,-94.73727275585145,119.05244058934628,-100.25905620452073,118.77021552104443,-92.43821236829586,104.15529386496785,-75.38914556448215,80.89099561359198,-53.8711647845645,55.463770389413234,-33.25627463685631,32.716175611062695,-16.99677937783543,16.063193207606343,-6.731200378998755,5.959161455816945,-1.537183837729182,1.3835328825787698,-23.999999999999943,6.67032204596957e-14,1.245406167676584e-13,1.4703831719607764e-13,2.5632650422903316e-13,2.1125691421248602e-13,3.014305387567766e-13,2.5312420566727674e-13,3.263294721136611e-13,2.705119068247448e-13,3.0616848128832963e-13,2.6452732877735657e-13,2.513171654396122e-13,2.384625893321381e-13,1.7188502873295985e-13,1.992919679733673e-13,7.237692304769979e-14,1.566343367477935e-13,-3.181994344332885e-14,1.1841869015096767e-13,-1.2068261501707508e-13,8.829555432128558e-14,-1.8058564072506982e-13,6.682713886443883e-14,-2.0745844624845483e-13,5.6610293783247607e-14,-2.0269973181573283e-13,6.458216506803031e-14,-1.711473367247439e-13,9.522438100091545e-14,-1.1813075741260172e-13,1.407680983530586e-13,-6.384802726290595e-14,1.762883615109664e-13,-2.1819592555661978e-14,1.8925477518271193e-13,5.925989391252889e-15,2.007038813065584e-13,2.897604295251666e-14,2.2096332135585036e-13,3.863827871501308e-14"""
```

---

```
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), header=None, skiprows=1, dtype=np.float64)
```

---

```
print (df)

           0          1          2          3           4           5    \
0 -2.872466e+13  16.966026 -42.872392  37.069693  -74.260196   57.915234   
1 -2.141387e+01  -2.528271  -6.930846  -5.011282  -11.185449  -13.824950   
2 -1.212549e+01 -34.097947  38.069089 -76.203091   65.788970 -102.031236   
3 -1.244381e+01  -0.779743  35.462719  -1.071343   55.599172   -4.444181   
4 -3.975479e+01  15.788824 -94.727030  34.906344 -155.264974   47.396292   
5 -3.464403e+01 -11.455829 -70.909376 -25.069863 -119.175645  -29.475460   
6 -1.284088e+01   0.280612  34.539587   0.501471   55.620391   -4.969447   
7 -2.467262e+01  16.814402 -22.519158  36.700027  -33.086659   55.521769   

          6           7           8           9    ...           154  \
0  -89.634102   64.410091  -98.674906   67.134329  ...  1.407681e-13   
1  -14.372899  -11.704558  -14.970243  -14.073952  ...  1.407681e-13   
2   80.605293 -123.586367   88.641401 -126.409286  ...  1.407681e-13   
3   76.532371   -2.699100   80.652746   -3.487173  ...  1.407681e-13   
4 -204.643120   58.051664 -219.681075   59.205304  ...  1.407681e-13   
5 -149.540377  -40.114085 -164.001946  -39.697517  ...  1.407681e-13   
6   74.232346   -1.982598   78.527627   -4.258158  ...  1.407681e-13   
7  -48.780388   63.239863  -52.371760   64.921119  ...  1.407681e-13   

            155           156           157           158           159  \
0 -6.384803e-14  1.762884e-13 -2.181959e-14  1.892548e-13  5.925989e-15   
1 -6.384803e-14  1.762884e-13 -2.181959e-14  1.892548e-13  5.925989e-15   
2 -6.384803e-14  1.762884e-13 -2.181959e-14  1.892548e-13  5.925989e-15   
3 -6.384803e-14  1.762884e-13 -2.181959e-14  1.892548e-13  5.925989e-15   
4 -6.384803e-14  1.762884e-13 -2.181959e-14  1.892548e-13  5.925989e-15   
5 -6.384803e-14  1.762884e-13 -2.181959e-14  1.892548e-13  5.925989e-15   
6 -6.384803e-14  1.762884e-13 -2.181959e-14  1.892548e-13  5.925989e-15   
7 -6.384803e-14  1.762884e-13 -2.181959e-14  1.892548e-13  5.925989e-15   

            160           161           162           163  
0  2.007039e-13  2.897604e-14  2.209633e-13  3.863828e-14  
1  2.007039e-13  2.897604e-14  2.209633e-13  3.863828e-14  
2  2.007039e-13  2.897604e-14  2.209633e-13  3.863828e-14  
3  2.007039e-13  2.897604e-14  2.209633e-13  3.863828e-14  
4  2.007039e-13  2.897604e-14  2.209633e-13  3.863828e-14  
5  2.007039e-13  2.897604e-14  2.209633e-13  3.863828e-14  
6  2.007039e-13  2.897604e-14  2.209633e-13  3.863828e-14  
7  2.007039e-13  2.897604e-14  2.209633e-13  3.863828e-14  

[8 rows x 164 columns]
```